# How to import data from csv file

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I'm new in neo4j and I'm trying to import data from two csv files, but I'm not able to do it.
The two csv files have the following structure:

master.csv:

```
ID    NAME    LASTNAME     COLLEGE
```

```
01    aaa     bbb          ABC
02    xxx     yyy          BCE
```

award.csv:

```
playerID    award                  year
```

```
01          best_player            2010
01          rookie_of_the_year     2011
02          best_player            2012
```

How can I create nodes for players and awards and how can I connect them?

I tried using this code: (but obviously it does not work)

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:PLAYER) ASSERT a.id IS UNIQUE;

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:AWARD) ASSERT b.award IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "File:///master.csv" as line fieldterminator ';'
CREATE (:PLAYER {id:line.playerID, name:line.firstName, lastName:line.lastName});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "File:///award.csv" as line fieldterminator ';'
MATCH (player:Player {id:line.playerID})
MERGE (award:AWARD {award:line.award})
CREATE (player)-[r:won]->(award)
set r += {year:line.year}
```

If I would also add nodes for colleges, is it right?

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:COLLEGE) ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///master.csv" as line fieldterminator ';'
WITH line
MATCH (player:PLAYER {id:line.playerID})
MERGE (college:COLLEGE {name:line.college}})
CREATE (player)-[:studied]->(college)
```

Thanks

Comment: *    ...MATCH (player:PLAYER)...

Comment: Everything looks fine, the problem might be that you try to run it in single transaction... you have to create each constraint in separate transaction and then run the first LOAD CSV and second one separately

Comment: Yes, I run each query separately.
Could be the problem on the csv files?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see its mainly a matter of using the correct CASE/case/Case in your statements. Based on what you displayed to be the input I came up with this (working for me) :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:PLAYER) ASSERT a.id IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:AWARD) ASSERT b.award IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///master.csv" as line fieldterminator ';'
CREATE (:PLAYER {id:line.bioID, name:line.firstName, lastName:line.lastName});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///award_players.csv" as line fieldterminator ';'
WITH line
MATCH (player:PLAYER {id:line.playerID})
MERGE (award:AWARD {award:line.award})
CREATE (player)-[r:won]->(award)
SET r += {year:line.year};
```

Hope this helps, Tom

Comment: First of all thanks for answering me, but when i run the second command it returns me the following:
(no changes, no records)

Comment: Can you share the actual content (header and first couple of lines will do) of the input-files (the above can not be them since you state you use ; as separator). If anything differs case-wise it will not work.

Comment: Yes sure, both files have the same format.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mgjcsh6b7k9v63c/award_players.csv?dl=0

I tried also with fieldterminator '\t', but have the same result

Comment: Ok, the award_players.csv is consistent with your and my statements. Can you also share the master.csv file ?

Comment: of course, thank you!!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg4h676y2ftkhzg/master.csv?dl=0

Comment: Not a problem. I edited my answer above based on the files you provided and I can guarantee :-) now that it'll work as such.

Comment: I say my stupid error :) .Thank you so much Tom, if you can I would have a last question...
I would create nodes for colleges now, is the code that I added on the post right?